# Weird dates when navigating in a calendar

Tags: php, date, calendar

I use this code to navigate 1 week back and forth on a weekly calendar starting mondays:

```
$date = $sysback->input->get("date", false);
$date = ($date) ? $date : date("Y-m-d");

$time = strtotime($date);
$year = date("Y", $time);
$week = date("W", $time);

$date_from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year."W".$week));
$date_to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year."W".$week." +6days"));

$date_prev = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year."W".$week." -7days"));
$date_next = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year."W".$week." +7days"));
```

But the problem is that if I go back from this week to 2014, I get weird dates:

- Date today: 2015-01-07
- 1 step back: 2014-12-29
- 2 steps back: 2013-12-23

Comment: I've never trusted "week numbers". This is probably why. Just go "current date -7 days" if you can. Or even "monday -7 days"

Comment: `strtotime` really? I thought we left this in the 90s :P use the `DateTime` class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are mixing calendar years and ISO 8601 week numbers.
ISO weeks usually span the calendar year boundary so using the calendar year there will get you the wrong answer,

You need to use `'o'` instead of `'Y'` in your `date()` call to determine `$year`
this will get you the apropriate year number to match the week number

```
$year = date("o", $time);
```